# How to indicate that the line in a grid view is clickable?

Tags: lists, grid

We are working on a small candidate management app where a list of candidates is shown in a simple table/grid view.
The business logic of an app requires to show all candidates in a grid but allow the user to go into the details only for the ones that user has permissions for.
Also, the initial design was made in a way that instead of having a button that leads into candidate details, the entire row in a grid is clickable.

So, at this point, we have a grid view with a list of candidates that shows an `hand` cussor for clickable items and regular `arror` for the ones that are not. But this setup makes it difficult to see from the list what is clickable and what is not.

What could be a solution for this problem? How to indicate that the item is clickable (editable) in the list, without forcing the user to scan through the list with a mouse?

[image]

Thanks,
A.

Comment: Is it possible for you to attach a screen shot of the grid to help gain a bit more perspective?

Comment: I added the screenshot to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion: leave the uneditable rows in gray, maybe also in italic font (and the editable ones in the standard colour).

In websites, clickable links are colored (standard: blue or purple), unclickable text are in black.

Comment: Another solution is bold the clickable rows. I would avoid using colors to assign too many meanings. Generally, less color = cleaner design. Also, color is not good for people with color blindness.

Answer (score 0):

While the entire row is clickable, you can still make it seem to the user like there's a button leading into the user details. For instance, you can make a column that says "details" and holds either an icon (an arrow, a chevron, a link etc.), or a hyperlink saying something like details/view/open etc. Alternatively you can use the candidate's name as the link in case of editable entities, and leave it unlinked for entities with no permissions. See example from JIRA. In this case all rows lead to editable entities, but the point is the indication - in each row there's a link leading to the entity (the name of the issue and its number)

[image]

Comment: Is there an example of something like that?

Comment: Yes, see updated post.